# Linear operator $T$ whose square is the average of $T$ and $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products

Having trouble with a question and I will be thankful for a hint.

Let $V$ be a an inner-product space with finite dimension over $\Bbb C$, $\space$ $T : V \to V$ linear transformation such that $T^2 =\frac12(T+T^*)$

A) Prove that $T$ is normal

B) Prove that $T^2-T=0$

So A was ok, since $T^*=2T^2-T$, and $T$ commutes with any polynomial in $T$, so $T$ is normal.

Having trouble with solving B, I've tried to use the fact that $T$ is diagonalizable and tried also some algebra techniques, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Sorry for my horrible English, I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: With V an inner product space, what, exactly, does "T^2- T" mean?  I would expect T^2 to be the inner product of T with itself but then it is a scalar and it would make no sense to subtract T.

Comment: @user247327 $T$ is a linear operator, so $T^2$ is a composition of $T$ with itself, in other words $T\circ T$. You can take $T$ as a matrix, if you want.

Comment: i mean that V is a vector space with the additional structure of inner product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: If $T$ is normal and $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $T^*$ with eigenvalue $\overline\lambda$. From this you conclude that any eigenvalue $\lambda$ must satisfy $\overline\lambda = 2\lambda^2-\lambda$. Do some algebra to conclude that $\lambda$ must be either $0$ or $1$, and so $T=T^*$ and $T$ is a projection.

Comment: Thanks.

just to make sure, i can take the matrices since T is normal and we are over $\Bbb C$ than there exists orthonormal basis $B$ for $V$ composed of eignvectors and use that ${[T^*]}_{B} = {[T]^*}_{B}$ and  ${[\frac{T+T^*}2]}_{B}$ =$\frac{1}2\cdot({[T]}_{B} + {[T^*]}_{B}) $ and do the calculations on the matrices?

Comment: You can do that. I had in mind just considering an eigenvector $v$: $Tv=\lambda v$, so $T^*v = \overline\lambda v$ and $2\lambda^2 v = 2T^2 v = Tv + T^*v = (\lambda+\overline\lambda)v$. Since $v\ne 0$, what I said follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: applying the given equation to any eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda\in\Bbb C$, gives that the eigenvalue satisfies $\lambda^2=\frac12(\lambda+\overline\lambda)=\Re\lambda$. It is easy to see that the only solutions to that equation are real, and then $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$ follows.

And a diagonalisable operator, all of whose eigenvalues are roots of a given polynomial (here $X^2-X$), is itself annihilated by that polynomial.